# Tabbed document interface Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: user-interface, ms-word, tabbed-interface

Someone, back in the day (2001) wrote a script to create a Doc-Bar in Word XP that would allow for tabbed interface of open Word documents (thus saving precious Taskbar space):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155741(office.10).aspx

However, the links/script mentioned in the package have mysteriously disappeared.

Does anyone know how to *programatically* create a document bar in Word 2007 that would allow for tabbed interface with open documents?

Comment: But the windows taskbar can group windows of the same programme.

Comment: Next time, use the link function to add links to your question. Just writing out a link will break if the link contains parentheses.

Comment: This is true, but not the solution. I find the grouping to miserable. What would be nicest is an Alt-tab to the program, then ctrl-tab through the open docs (like you can in most other tab enabled programs (firefox notepad++ etc.)

Comment: @OregonGhost: Inserting links requires a certain rep (This is to avoid link spam).

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the same question, but what about something like WinTabber? (http://www.wintabber.com/) - I used to use this (or something like it) for tabbed PuTTY sessions before I built mrxvt for Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

There's several things you could do using Word options:

- Go to *Word Options* -> *Advanced* -> *Display* section and uncheck *Show all windows in Taskbar*
- Use the Window list (on the View tab of the ribbon) to switch between documents. Default shortcut would be (on an English UI): `Alt+W+W+<n>` where n is the index of your document.
- Configure a custom keyboard shortcut to bring up the list of open documents.